# Show that sum obtained in this chessboard is already 260

Tags: summation

Consider the square of an $8 \times 8 $ chessboard filled with the number $1$ to $64$ as in given figure .If we choose $8$ squares with the property that is exactly one from each row and exactly one from each column , and add up the numbers in the chosen squares , show that sum obtained is always $260$ .

[image: Figure]
**My work**

I can just observer that it is happening but I don't know how to prove it .
$$1+10+29+28+37+46+55+64$$
$$2+11+20+29+38+47+56+57$$
I know many pair like are existing but how I will show this ?

Comment: @smcc How he this  -If we choose $8$ squares with the property that there is exactly one from each row and exactly one from each column, with this notation the total is $$8 \cdot \biggl( \sum_{i=0}^{7}i \biggr) + \sum_{j=1}^{8} j = 260$$

Comment: An individual number from row $i+1$ column $j$, is of the form $8i+j$. Since we cannot have any of the same $i$'s or $j$'s, then the indices $i$ and $j$ run over all their possible values. Try writing out the $i$'s and $j$'s for your examples.

Comment: There is another proof : choose 8 squares with the property and consider it as $8\times 8$ permutation matrix. Now you can show that exchanging two rows (or columns) does not change the summation, because the numbers $a(i_{1}, j_{1}), a(i_{1}, j_{2}), a(i_{2}, j_{1}), a(i_{2}, j_{2})$ satisfies $a(i_{1}, j_{1})+a(i_{2}, j_{2}) = a(i_{2}, j_{1})+a(i_{1}, j_{2})$. Since we can change the matrix into identity matrix by suitable transpositions, the sum is always constant with value $1+10+19+28+37+46+55+64=260$.